# How to apply this function recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i got this function `aux`, it's easy to understand. What this function
does is see how many numbers are greater than the first element of a
list.

```
list1 = [5,2,7,4,3,8]

def aux(list1):
    x=list1[0]
    res=1
    for number in range(1,len(list1)):
        if(list1[number]>x):
            res+=1
    return res
```

and now i want to make another function that use `aux` recursively for
each element of the list and see who returns the greater number. But i
am not seeing how can i do this recursively.

Comment: Do you mean 'using recursion' by _recursive_? Why do you want to do that recursively? Is it a part of the task?

Comment: yes, it's part of the task

Comment: What's the task? The program doesn't count how many numbers are greater than the first, and it doesn't count how many numbers are >= than the first.

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: in this example my expected result is 3, because are 2 more numbers greater than 5, 7 and 8. So, res start at 1 because we count the number 5 too, 1+2=3

Comment: But 5 is not greater than 5.

Comment: It may help to add some pseudocode to show what you're trying to achieve.  I'm not clear on what result you're trying to achieve.   Also take a look at `itertools`, your `aux` function can be reduced down to a couple lines using those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not a part of the question, but I would rewrite the function like this:

```py
def count_gt(x, container):
    greater_than_x = 0
    for number in container:
        if number > x:
            greater_than_x += 1
    return greater_than_x
```

Let's look at some examples of recursion to make it easier.

Sum of the list:

```py
def get_sum(container):
    if container == []:
        return 0
    else:
        return container[0] + get_sum(container[1:])
```

Using a loop, you can solve the problem easily:

```py
greatest = 0
for number in numbers:
    greatest = max(count_gt_first(number), greatest)
```

If your task is to find the maximum number in a list of positive numbers, it can be expressed recursively like this:

```py
def get_max(container):
    if len(container) == 1:
        return container[0]
    else:
        return max(container[0], get_max(container[1:]))
```

For example:

```
get_max([4, 3, 9, 1])
    --> max(4, get_max[3, 9, 1])
    --> max(5, max(3, get_max[9, 1]))
    --> max(5, max(3, max(9, get_max[1])))
    --> max(5, max(3, max(9, 1)))
    <-- max(5, max(3, 9))
    <-- max(5, 9)
    <-- 9
```

Now you can modify the function to find not the maximum value, but the maximum result of the function for a value.

```py
def get_max(container):
    return _get_max(container, container)

def _get_max(container, original_container):
    if len(container) == 1:
        return container
    else:
        result_for_this = count_gt(container[0], container)
        candidate_for_rest = _get_max(container[1:], container)
        result_for_rest = count_gt(candidate_for_rest, container)
        if result_for_this > result_for_rest:
            return container[0]
        else:
            return candidate_for_rest
```

You can rewrite the function to use *tail recursion*:

```py
def get_max(container):
    return _get_max(container, container, container[0])

def _get_max(container, original_container, max_candidate):
    if count_gt(container[0], container) > count_gt(max_candidate, container):
        max_candidate = container[0]
    if len(container) == 1:
        return max_candidate
    return _get_max(container[1:], original_container, max_candidate)
```

Read more on recursion:

https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/

https://chrispenner.ca/posts/python-tail-recursion

Answer (score 2):

> now i want to make another function that use aux recursively for each element of the list and see who returns the greater number.

I understand you may be tasked with solving this in a specifically recursive way, but I don't see the need. The element in your list that will return the greatest number using your function's logic is just the lowest number. This can be found with the `min()` function. You can then either return the length of your list minus one (if you assume no duplicates) or the length of your list minus the length of another list that only includes your lowest items (should there be duplicates.)

```
# Assums no duplicates    
def something(l):
    return (min(l), len(l)-1)

# Accounts for duplicates 
def betterthing(l):
    low = min(l)
    return (low, len(l) - len([x for x in l if x == low]))

l1 = [5,2,7,4,3,8]
print("{} is lowest & {} other items are larger.".format(*something(l1)))

l2 = [5,2,7,4,3,8,2,9,10,8]
print("{} is lowest & {} other items are larger.".format(*betterthing(l2)))
```

[Example code in Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%23%20Assums%20no%20duplicates%20%20%20%20%0Adef%20something%28l%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%28min%28l%29,%20len%28l%29-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%23%20Accounts%20for%20duplicates%20%0Adef%20betterthing%28l%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20low%20%3D%20min%28l%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%28low,%20len%28l%29%20-%20len%28%5Bx%20for%20x%20in%20l%20if%20x%20%3D%3D%20low%5D%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Al1%20%3D%20%5B5,2,7,4,3,8%5D%0Aprint%28%22%7B%7D%20is%20lowest%20%26%20%7B%7D%20other%20items%20are%20larger.%22.format%28*something%28l1%29%29%29%0A%0Al2%20%3D%20%5B5,2,7,4,3,8,2,9,10,8%5D%0Aprint%28%22%7B%7D%20is%20lowest%20%26%20%7B%7D%20other%20items%20are%20larger.%22.format%28*betterthing%28l2%29%29%29%0A&cumulative=true&curInstr=3&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Edit:

> What this function does is see how many numbers are greater than the first element of a list.

That seems like a inaccurate way to describe your function. Since you initialize your `res` variable to 1 it actually returns how many numbers are greater than the first element in the list plus 1.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
list1 = [5,2,7,4,3,8]

def aux(list1,i,res,x):
    if (i+1)>len(list1):
        print('end')
        print(res)
    else:
        if list1[i]>x:
            print('element '+str(i)+' greater than first element')
            res+=1
        aux(list1,i+1,res,x) #recursion happens here


aux(list1,i,1,list1[0])
```

Comment: when you call the function,  what is your "i"?

Comment: so when I originally define the function with `def aux(...)` one of the arguments is `i` - this is the number element in `list1`. On the line that I have commented `recursion happens here` I am inputting `i` again only I am adding 1 to it. Hence the function is calling itself but with an updated `i`.